How to get emf image as input stream from system clipboard?
Copying an image in ChemDraw (vector graphics editor for molecular structures, smth like Inkscape) brings to System Clipboard an emf image what follows from lines CF_ENHMETAFILE and CF_METAFILEPICT in Inside Clipboard: I need to get an image as InputStream to convert into PNG using FreeHEP. As far as I know this and other libraries need emf as a file or InputStream.
I tried to use this code for CF_METAFILEPICT and CF_ENHMETAFILE
String clipboardName = "CF_METAFILEPICT";
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
SystemFlavorMap flavorMap = (SystemFlavorMap) SystemFlavorMap.getDefaultFlavorMap();
DataFlavor myDataFlavor = new DataFlavor(java.io.InputStream.class, "");
flavorMap.addFlavorForUnencodedNative(clipboardName , myDataFlavor);
InputStream data = (InputStream) clipboard.getData(myDataFlavor);

The last line gives an exception java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException: application/x-java-serialized-object, but it works for other objects (see picture from Inside Clipboard).

Thats because it's not an input stream but a metafile image. You need to supply that to whatever API class can read it

@g00se Could you recommend any class for this?

Maybe take a look here
